# Grunt compass change outputStyle on deploy

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, gruntjs

My Gruntfile checks which Git branch I'm on (dev, test or prod) and if "prod" I want to minify/compress the CSS with compass (grunt-contrib-compass).
But I'm unable to change the `outputStyle` property in compass `options`.

However I'm able to change my custom `meta.build.outputStyle` to "compressed" in the deploy function, but unable to change `compass.site_x.options.outputStyle` by reading that meta variable. Any ideas?

Gruntfile summary (parts excluded):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    meta:{
      build: {
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
      }
    },
    compass: {
      site_x: {
        options: { // Target options
          sassDir: 'sass',
          specify: 'sass/legacy/main.scss',
          cssDir: 'dist/styles',
          imagesDir: "images",
          outputStyle: "<%= meta.build.outputStyle %>",
          config: "./config.rb"
        }
      }
    },
    .... //misc
  });
  .... //misc

  function deploy(environment) {
    if(environment === "prod") {
        grunt.log.oklns("Starting deploy to PROD");
        grunt.config.set("meta.build.outputStyle", "compressed");
        grunt.log.oklns("outputStyle: "+grunt.config.get('meta').build.outputStyle); // prints "compressed"
    }
  }
 ....
```